# Choppy animation bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, animation, jquery-animate

I use the bootstrap collapse class on some html elements.
Then, with jquery, I dynamically show the collapsed elements.
An example of this:(html:)

```
<form>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="1">checkbox1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_level collapse">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="2">checkbox2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="3">checkbox3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="4">checkbox4</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

(javascript:)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#1").click(function(){
        $("div.sub_level").collapse("toggle");
    });

});
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10346/

Reading about this issue I've read that it's the padding that causes this problem. removing the padding fixes it but I don't want to remove the padding.
Also, wrapping the collapsing element in a div sometimes fixes the problem but sometimes doesn't.
I was wondering if there is a core reason for this problem so that I can fix.
I tried using jquery show/hide and using `style='display:none;'` instead of the bootstrap collapse class but it's the same problem.
It doesn't seems logical that I can't use such a simple animation method.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it with jQuery so you're not dependent on Bootstrap `collapse`.

```js
$('#checkChange').click(function() {
  this.checked ? $('#opened').fadeIn(300) : $('#opened').fadeOut(100);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 25px 0;
}
#opened {
  display: none;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
#checkIt .form-control {
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 50px;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  color: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: #000;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <form name="checkIt" id="checkIt">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkChange" />
          <label for="checkChange">Check It Out</label>
          <div id="opened">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="one" />Check It</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Check It Out</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="three" />Check It Out Again</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```